# next js run script right after page load / nextjs 13 app / only works if there is an error / react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, server-side-rendering

I deliberately simplified the task to make it easier for you to understand.

*My goal* - is when the page loads (useEffect) the JavaScript code changes the color of the text. I shouldn't be able to see the default color since useEffect runs instantly. **I have to instantly see blue**

```
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

  export default function index() {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.style.color = 'blue'
  }, []);

  return <h1 ref={ref}>12345</h1>;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-nzjwdb?file=app%2Fpage.js - example

*In practice* - all JavaScript code in Next js runs with a delay. Because of this, I see the text in the default color for a second.

In an article with a similar problem, it was proposed to create a custom hook useIsomorphicLayoutEffect. My code should be like this:

```
'use client';
import React, { useRef,useEffect,useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

const useIsomorphicLayoutEffect =
  typeof window !== 'undefined' ? useLayoutEffect : useEffect;

export default function index() {
  const ref = useRef();
  useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current.style.color = 'blue'
  }, []);

  return <h1 ref={ref}>12345</h1>;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-2dc5z4?file=app%2Fpage.js - example, custom hook, behavior unchanged

It didn't work. I still saw the default color at the beginning.

**Then I made a mistake!** If it's wrong to write "useEffect" in a custom hook, the script works as I want! When the page loads, the color is instantly blue!!!

```
const useIsomorphicLayoutEffect =
  typeof window !== 'undefined' ? useLayoutEffect : useEffectBlaBlaBlaRandomText;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-ofguvu?file=app%2Fpage.js - example, expected behavior with error in console

**I don't know why it works like this. The code works correctly only on error**

But I am getting an error in the console that "useEffectBlaBlaBlaRandomText is not defined"
What can I do to make everything work and there are no errors in the console?